# Ant build file to include also the derby database jar

Tags: java, ant, build

Hy,

I have an RMI, Client Server app which needs also the Derby database driver to be includes on the server side

My tree structure looks like the following:

```
s
│   buildcmmdc.xml
│   MyAnt.bat
│
├───lib
│       derbyclient.jar
│
└───src
    └───server
            derbyclient.jar
            ZodiacChinezesc.java
            Zodie.java
            ZodieImpl.java
```

My Ant build file cmmdcbuild1.xml

```
<project name="Server" default="Install" basedir=".">
    <description>Server actions </description>

  <property name="path" location=".."/>
  <property name="lib-dir" location="${path}/s/lib"/>
  <property name="package" value="server"/>
  <property name="interface-jar" location="${path}/i/public/classes/zodie" />
  <property name="jar-file" value="zodie.jar" />
  <property name="service-class" value="ZodieImpl"  />
  <property name="port" value="1099"/>
  <property name="hostRMIRegistry" value="localhost"/>
  <property name="hostResources" value="localhost"/>
  <property name="DERBY_HOME" location="D:/soft/db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin"/>

  <target name="Install">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <delete dir="src"/>
    <mkdir dir="src"/>
    <delete dir="public"/>
    <mkdir dir="public"/>
    <delete dir="public/classes"/>
    <mkdir dir="public/classes"/>
  </target>

  <target name="Init">
    <mkdir dir="src/${package}"/>
    <mkdir dir="public/classes/${package}"/>
    <copy file="${interface-jar}/${jar-file}" todir="public/classes" />
  </target>

<path id="jars">
    <fileset dir="${lib-dir}"> <include name="*.jar"/> </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${DERBY_HOME}/lib/derby.jar" /> 
</path>

  <target name="Compile" depends="Init"
        description="compile the source " >
    <javac srcdir="src"
       includes="${package}/**" destdir="public/classes"
       classpath="public/classes/${jar-file}"
    classpathref="jars"
       includeantruntime="false"/>
    <unjar  src="public/classes/${jar-file}" dest="public/classes" />
  </target>

  <target name="Archive">
     <jar destfile="zodie.jar" basedir="public/classes">
       <include name="${package}/*"/>
       <include name="zodie/*"/>
     </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="Rmi">
     <exec executable="rmiregistry">
       <env key="classpath" value="public/classes"/>
       <arg value="${port}" />
     </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="Server">
     <java classname="${package}.${service-class}"
        classpath="${path}/s/public/classes" fork="true">  
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${path}/s/public/classes/"/>    
        <!-- <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=server.policy" />-->
        <!-- <jvmarg value="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=guliguli" />-->
        <!--
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://${hostResources}:8080/rmi/zodie.jar" />
        -->
        <!--
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=ftp://${hostResources}:2121/rmi/zodie.jar" />
        -->
        <arg line="${hostRMIRegistry} ${port}"/>
     </java>
  </target> 
</project>
```

I see not to get the derbyclient.jar to be imported into my server side and it dosen't find my driver.

How to modify the build in order to add also the database driver.

Sincereley,

`

Comment: which target are you running and whats the issue?

Comment: Target is Server. The issue is that when the client ask for data from database, I receive a message from my class that deals with derby driver (class not found exception: no driver found for org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Comment: The order in which I run the tagets is: Compile, Rmi and with RMI opened I use Server as target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your java tag, use [classpathref](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) attribute as below:

```
<java ..... classpathref="jars">
```